# How do I use WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE to insert into the MySQL db?

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I'm having trouble using the WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE, for the WP REST API POST.

I'm trying to insert into the database via POST, but it doesn't work.  I was able to get it working via GET but not POST:

```
<?php

// Register REST API endpoints
class GenerateWP_Custom_REST_API_Endpoints {

  /**
   * Register the routes for the objects of the controller.
   */
  public static function register_endpoints() {
    register_rest_route( 'ibl/api/interview', '/greeting', array(
      'methods' => WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE,
      'callback' => array( 'GenerateWP_Custom_REST_API_Endpoints', 'create_greeting' ),
    ) );
  }

  /**
   * Add a new greeting
   *
   * @param WP_REST_Request $request Full data about the request.
   * @return List
   */
  public static function create_greeting( $request ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $item = $request->get_json_params();

    $fields = array();
    $values = array();
    foreach($item as $key => $val) {
        array_push($fields, preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", '', $key));
        array_push($values, $wpdb->prepare('%s', $val));
    }
    $fields = implode(", ", $fields);
    $values = $_GET["greeting"];

    $query = "INSERT INTO wp_api (GREETING) VALUES ('$values')";
    $list = $wpdb->get_results($query);

    return $list;
  }
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', array( 'GenerateWP_Custom_REST_API_Endpoints', 'register_endpoints' ) );
```

?greeting=ititit

Thank you

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Having the exact same problem. When I use `WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE` (POST) I get a `rest_no_route` error but when I change it to `WP_REST_Server::READABLE` (GET) the endpoint is accessible

Comment: @elmediano you need to actually send some POST data (in body) to the endpoint, otherwise you wil see `rest_no_route`

Comment: @ArturCzyżewski thanks for this. I managed to get it work back in the day by doing just that. Forgot to mention it here!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Im i litle late but I think your problem would be fixed adding a nonce.

Wordpress has a security system in REST APIs based in nonces. Maybe is clear for you that you could use it in plugins forms and settings by using the function `wp_create_nonce()` where the first argument is the name of the nonce.

You could Enqueue a JS script and then declare a 'global variable' by using `wp_localize_script()`

Then you could declare a nonce as following:

```
wp_enqueue_script('mm_main_js',plugin_dir_url( __FILE__).'js/main.js',array('jquery'), '1.0', true);

wp_localize_script( 'mm_main_js', 'ajax_requests', array(
  'site_url'=>site_url(),
  'my_new_nonce'=>wp_create_nonce( 'any_nonce_name' )

));
```

Ok, the thing is that when you are using the native Worpress REST API and you create a custom route or even you are using the API for creating posts, deleting them, etc., you MUST use the nonce name 'wp_rest'; it is mandatory.

So you must change the previous snipet by:

```
'my_new_nonce'=>wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' )
```

So let's supose you have the following JS script for posting some information in the custom route.

```
async deleteRequest(dataId, deleteUrl){

const deleteRequest = await fetch(deleteUrl, {
  method: "POST",
  credentials: "same-origin",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "X-WP-Nonce": ajax_requests.my_new_nonce, //It is important to send the nonce in this format and on the headers request section
  },
  body:JSON.stringify({
    //Your data
  })
})

return deleteRequest;
```

}

Remember that `ajax_requests` is the name of the array created by `wp_localize_script` and, as any other object or array in JS you access to any value by coding `ajax_scripts.variable`, in this case, the nonce created.

Hope it works for you.